# Issue when saving form data using SprinBoot + Jpa + vaadin

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, vaadin-flow

I am using SpringBoot along with JPA and Vaadin-flow. I am getting this error while trying to save the Form Data.

I try to add @Repository Annotation in CustomerRepository class, but still it is not working. Can someone please help me on this.

## Customer.java

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    protected Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
        //Getters ans Setters

}
```

## CustomerEditor.java

```
@Route(value = "NewPickUp", layout = MainView.class)
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
public class CustomerEditor extends VerticalLayout{

    @Autowired
    private final CustomerRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private Customer customer;

    TextField firstName = new TextField("First name");
    TextField lastName = new TextField("Last name");
    Button save = new Button("Save", VaadinIcon.CHECK.create());

    Binder<Customer> binder = new Binder<>(Customer.class);

    @Autowired
    public CustomerEditor(CustomerRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
        add(firstName, lastName, save );
        binder.forField(firstName).bind(Customer::getFirstName, Customer::setFirstName);
        binder.forField(lastName).bind(Customer::getLastName, Customer::setLastName);

        save.addClickListener(e -> save());
    }

    void save() {
        repository.save(customer);
    }
}
```

## CustomerRepository.java

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByLastNameStartsWithIgnoreCase(String lastName);
}
```

## MainView.java

```
@Route
public class MainView extends AppLayout{
     public MainView() {

    Button addButton = new Button(new RouterLink("", CustomerEditor.class));
    RouterLink routerLink = new RouterLink("NewPickUp", CustomerEditor.class);
        routerLink.getElement().appendChild(addButton.getElement());
        this.addToNavbar(routerLink); 

     }
```

## Error Message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.apt.lts.view.CustomerEditor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.apt.lts.model.Customer' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:305) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator.getOrCreate(SpringInstantiator.java:117) ~[vaadin-spring-12.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:158) ~[flow-server-2.0.11.jar:2.0.11]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:127) ~[flow-server-2.0.11.jar:2.0.11]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: what is package of public class Customer {

Comment: `Customer` class belongs to `com.apt.lts.model;`

Comment: have you enabled jpa repositories  @EnableJpaRepositories on Application class also add @ Repository annotation on your repository

Comment: @Shailesh i tried above option. Unfortunately it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Debendra Dhinda mentions in their answer, your `Customer` class is not a Spring Component and can therefore not be injected. You can either NOT inject a customer instead create a new Customer in the constructor in the view, or you can add a `@Bean` definition method in your `@Configuration` class. What both approaches have in common is that you call `new Customer()` at some point.

```
// code example for approach 2
@Configuration
public class MySpringConfiguration {

    // this method will be called if you inject/autowire a Customer somewhere.
    @Bean
    public Customer getCustomer(){
        return new Customer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above error clearly specifies that the You are trying to `Autowired` a bean which is not a Spring managed bean (`Customer` here).

These beans are defined in xml form with  tag, or with some special annotations like `@Bean, @Component, @Service, @Repository` etc.

In simple terms, entities are some java objects that you will need to create, update by yourself according to your business logic and save/update/remove them in/from DB. Their life-cycle cannot be managed by Spring IoC container.